# Appearance dialog doesn't work in 12.04 Unity

Tags: unity, virtualbox, appearance

When I open Settings - Appearance, there are two problems:

1. I selected color (non-wallpaper) background, and is shown as current background. However, the desktop background does not change.
2. There is no Launcher Icon size slider in the bottom.

I see this in 12.04 64 bit Unity, running under VirtualBox. The same "parent" Ubuntu works as expected.

Comment: What do you get for `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`?

Comment: Good guess - it was in 2D mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by enabling 2D and 3D acceleration in VirtualBox settings, which allowed Ubuntu to run in 3D mode.